# Games on Facebook keep sending me to the sign in page

Tags: facebook, facebook-games

Games on Facebook (such as Bejewelled Blitz, Diamond Dash) that I have been playing for a long time (and played this morning) now won't load.

Clicking on a name makes the page jump to the Facebook sign-in page, but it keeps going in and out, flashing the log in page on and off.

I have gone and clicked Facebook in my favorites bar to get it back to the news feed page.

Any suggestions?